# Find the missing month in given date range then add that missing date in the data with same records as given in the last date

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, date, range

I have a Statement of accounts, where i have Unique ID, Disbursed date, payment date and the balance amount.

Date range for below data = Disbursed date to May-2022

Example of date:

```
Unique   Disbursed date      payment date   balance amount
123      2022-Jan-13          2022-Jan-27      10,000 
123      2022-Jan-13          2022-Feb-28       5,000 
123      2022-Jan-13          2022-Apr-29       2,000
```

1. first I want to groupby payment date(last day of each month) and as an aggr function instead of Sum or mean, I want to carry forward the same balance reflecting in the last month last day.
2. As you can see March is missing in the records, here I want to add a new record for March with same balance given in Feb-22 i.e 5,000 and date for the new record should be last day of Mar-22.
3. Since date range given till 2022-May then here I want to add another new record for May-22 with same balance given in last month (Apr-22) i.e 2000 and date for the new record should be last day of May-22

Note : I have multiple unique ids like 123, 456, 789, etc.

I'd tried below code to find out the missing month

for i in df['date']:
pd.date_range(i,'2020-11-28').difference(df.index)
print(i)

but, it is giving days wise missing date. I want to find out the missing "month" instead of date for each unique id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
# generate needed month ends
idx = pd.date_range('2022-01', '2022-06', freq='M')

out = (df
   # compute the month end for existing data
   .assign(month_end=pd.to_datetime(df['payment date'])
                       .sub(pd.Timedelta('1d'))
                       .add(pd.offsets.MonthEnd()))
   .set_index(['Unique', 'month_end'])
   # reindex with missing ID/month ends
   .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Unique'].unique(),
                                        idx
                                       ], names=['Unique', 'idx']))
   .reset_index()
   # fill missing month end with correct format
   .assign(**{'payment date': lambda d:
              d['payment date'].fillna(d['idx'].dt.strftime('%Y-%b-%d'))})
   # ffill the data per ID
   .groupby('Unique').ffill()
   
)
```

output:

```
   Unique        idx Disbursed date payment date balance amount
0     123 2022-01-31    2022-Jan-13  2022-Jan-27         10,000
1     123 2022-02-28    2022-Jan-13  2022-Feb-28          5,000
2     123 2022-03-31    2022-Jan-13  2022-Mar-31          5,000
3     123 2022-04-30    2022-Jan-13  2022-Apr-29          2,000
4     123 2022-05-31    2022-Jan-13  2022-May-31          2,000
```

Comment: Hi Mozway, appreciate your prompt response. I'd tried your code, but getting this error "ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!"

Comment: Then you have duplicated `payment date`/`Unique` combinations somewhere, which is not reflected in your example. Please provide an example that reproduces the error.

Comment: If we do groupby payment date at first then there will be no duplicate left in the data..

Comment: @SAIFANSARI that's a possibility, you know the real data ;)

Comment: Hi Mozway, Thanks a lot!!  your code is working totally fine after removing duplicates. :)